# Backups via WHM - setting the schedule specifically?

Tags: backup, whm

We have backups running via WHM to a FTP server - where I see we can set daily, weekly, monthly - but can we specify what time during the day the backups are being done so it won't interfere with other heavy server load tasks?

Looking at the emails I get when the backup is complete, it seems like it's doing it at all sorts of random times.

Also - is there a way to change the priority at which the backup is being run?

Answer (score 3):

In your WHM > cPanel section of left menu > Manage Plugins area, you'll find one listed there titled cronconfig. Tick the "Install and keep updated" box then scroll to bottom and click Save.

Then refresh your web page and scroll to 'Configure cPanel Cron Times' under Plugins, you can change the backup hour there.

Answer (score 0):

Although cPanel does not provide any direct control over that, I believe you should be able to change the day at which the backups are performed by changing /wsbackup/cpbackup/monthly's time stamp. cPanel will execute the backup when the directory is older than 29 days.

I am working to figure out how to specify an actual day.

Josh